# Selector reacts slowly - sometimes not firing at all before starting next activity

Tags: android

I have this Selector defined:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- PRESSED -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/backarrow_blueshiny" />

    <!-- FOCUSED --> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/backarrow_blackshiny" />

    <!-- DEFAULT -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/backarrow_blackshiny" />

</selector>
```

and it's used with this button:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/bottomborder_glossy">

        <!-- BACK -->
        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/filter_button_back"
        android:layout_width="90dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/selector_back_button"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the onTouch event consists of:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    final int actionPerformed = event.getAction();
    final int widgetID = v.getId();

    if (actionPerformed == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        switch (widgetID)
        {
            case R.id.filter_button_back:
            {
                this.finish();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

what this button does is exit the current activity `this.finish()` 
However, in my testing the button doesn't always switch to "backarrow_blueshiny" - namely when pressing very fast.

So the problem is that the selector fires slower than the onTouch(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) event.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that the selector isn't "laggy" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean laggier than the typical Android selector behavior? In my experience, there's always been a slight delay between a button press, and it being selected -- I assume it's to avoid showing a touch event when you're just wanting to scroll, but it's always annoyed me. If it's more than the typical behavior, try using just a button, with the `android:background` set to the selector, rather than an ImageButton with the `android:src` set to the selector.

e.g.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_back_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    />
```

Comment: your suggested method seems to have the same kind of reaction speed that I was already getting. I can still push really fast and the UI doesn't react but the ACTION_UP event is already triggered.

Comment: I'll mark your response as an answer since it seems unlikely to get more answers

Comment: Give people time. :) You don't have to accept it so soon, it's only been four hours. That said, the behavior you're describing is absolutely normal. Visually, you're not going to see the clicks happen as fast as you click it, but the events should all fire normally. It's just an Android quirk; every phone (Droid, Droid 2, Incredible, Droid X) I've used exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Try to set your view as pressed programmatically in OnTouchListener:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            button.setPressed(true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // optional, should work without next line
            // button.setPressed(false); 
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Great, that worked! That latency was driving me insane.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In the emulator it doesn't even changed button colour. It's caused by the "onTouch". If you use onClickListener instead of onTouchListener it will react as expected.

As I can see you are not using any multitouch capability so wy dont you use the onClick and get rid of the

```
   if (actionPerformed == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
```