# Android delay issue when button pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, button, delay

I just created a custom button and changed the different states. But when I pressed the button (I tried on a real device), the shape change is delayed, something like 300 ms. Does anyone know where it could come from?

button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button_primary" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button_primary" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_button_primary"/>
</selector>
```

normal_button_primary.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFCF01" />
</shape>
```

pressed_button_primary.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FEBF48" />
</shape>
```

Acitivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  Button login_button;
  Button signup_button;
  private static final String CONSOLETAG = "consoleDebug : ";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Click on signup button
    signup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Nothin
        }
    });

    // Click on login button
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Nothin
        }
    });
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  public void goToSignup(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: it might be the case that when you are pressing the button, some heavy operation is going on. Can you check that?

Comment: I checked and there is no operation attached to the click. I added a ClickListener just to print some content to the console, and this content is also print with delay in the console

Comment: It might also be the case that your images `pressed_button_primary` and `normal_button_primary` are of high resolutions which are taking time to load. Please post the images resolutions for better understanding/

Comment: the images are just shapes, no high res images. Maybe other apps causing this delay. How are your normal apps, not developed by You, acting? Floating or also with delay? You sould check this...

Comment: please post your onClick method

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The other apps respond very quickly, and it's still delayed even if it's the only app running. Can it be a problem of build?

Comment: The onClick method is empty
signup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Nothin done
            }
        });

Comment: @JohnJoe I'm having the exact same issue and it seems to be the same latency regardless of the phone that I'm using. Did you manage to find the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027628/658323

The issue happens because the system is trying to detect whether you want to press the view or to perform a scroll event, therefore it will wait some time before registering the event as `"press"`.

The solution is to register the press event dynamically from your code on `ACTION_DOWN`, while keeping the selector xml as it is:

```
yourSelectableView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        v.setPressed(true);
         break;
      }
    }
    return false; //we return false so that the click listener will process the event
  }
});
```